# Docker: Timeout waiting for an IP

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, docker-machine

On Windows x64, using Docker Toolbox and VirtualBox 6, when trying to create a new machine, it hangs for a **long** time at the "`Waiting for an IP...`" point, eventually timing out with this message:

> Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded

[image]

I've got the paths to both VirtualBox and Docker Toolbox in my environment path.

I'm still wet behind the ears with Docker; anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Same: https://superuser.com/a/1388161/726810

Comment: I've reproduced the same issue for Virtual Box 6.0 and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the issue I opened on both Docker and OpenSSH specifically dealing with this issue showing a full video reproduction of the issue, and the workaround including all the versions I tested:

https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4483

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1155

Before I posted this root cause and workaround/testing, I could find no reference to this ever being uncovered/reported and as far as I know, to date I cannot believe it is still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 version 1803 or higher ships with its own (beta) version of OpenSSH 7.7, a native port of the [OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/) project. Unfortunately, that version seems to be incompatible with the latest Docker Machine, hence it fails to connect properly.

You can try to uninstall the OpenSSH client by navigating to *Settings -> Apps -> Manage optional features (below Apps & features)* and clicking on *OpenSSH -> Uninstall*.

Alternatively, you can remove `C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\` from the Windows `PATH` environment variable.

Source: Courtesy of [Steve Cliff](https://local.getflywheel.com/community/t/cannot-get-vm-started-due-to-waiting-for-an-ip-maximum-number-of-retries-60-exceeded-error/4801/19)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I got a bit excited since it's the only real different answer I've seen so far in all my searching, but unfortunately, even after uninstalling Windows' OpenSSH and rebooting, the problem persists.